# Swift's Mapping Function

Tags: swift, swift2

From what I understand, Swift's `map` function does the following:

- Works on anything that adopts `SequenceType`
- Idea is to return another "something" (looking for a better term) that had it's elements transformed via the logic you pass into the closure
- Always returns "something" that still conforms to `SequenceType`, and the # of elements does not change

**For example:**

We have 2 classes **Milk** and **Cheese**. We're given the constructor for **Cheese**, which is the following:

```
init(withMilk milk: Milk) {
  self.milk = milk
}
```

Given an array of **Milk** objects, we turn an array of **Milk** objects into **Cheese** objects like so:

```
let arrayOfCheese = arrayOfMilk.map { Cheese(withMilk: $0) }
```

That works fine for me. But now I want something more than normal Cheese. I need ingredients from all over the place:

```
let arrayOfSuperCheese = arrayOfMilk.map { 
  let cheese = Cheese(usingMilk: $0)
  let sulfur = Sulfur()
  let minerals = Minerals()
  let mixer = Mixer()

  let superCheese = mixer.mixIn(sulphur: sulphur, minerals: minerals)
  return superCheese
}
```

Compiler told me:

`Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '(@noescape (Element) throws -> _)`

The above example is roughly the problem I'm having at the moment. Please let me know if that example made sense or not.

Comment: Your code example uses `withMilk`, but the usage uses `usingMilk`. Are you sure you don't have a typo in your code?

Comment: Fixed, sorry. I don't actually have this in code, just made it up to put in some context to my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sufficiently complicated that it cannot reasonable infer the closure signature. So specify it:

```
let arrayOfSuperCheese = arrayOfMilk.map { (milk: Milk) -> Cheese in
    let cheese = Cheese(usingMilk: milk)
    let sulfur = Sulfur()
    let minerals = Minerals()
    let mixer = Mixer()

    let superCheese = mixer.mixIn(sulfur: sulfur, minerals: minerals)
    return superCheese
}
```

Comment: Obviously, the `cheese` constant in this closure isn't being used, but I wanted to preserve your code snippet as much as possible. Also, as a matter of following common conventions, I would not use `usingMilk` (or `withMilk`, which you reference elsewhere) for the first parameter of `Cheese`, but rather just `milk`, but that's up to you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer and advice. It worked as soon as I explicitly defined the closure signature. Would you know when the exact point is that a explicit closure signature is required?

Comment: No, I don't know the exact threshold, but it's reproduced with examples much simpler than this. E.g. `let cheeses = milks.map { let cheese = Cheese(milk: $0); return cheese }`. There is some behavior that changes with multiline closures, so maybe that's it, but I suspect it might be more subtle than that. Bottom line, I write code with inferred types until such point that the compiler tells me it can no longer infer, and then I explicitly specify the parameters.